# gerund vs participle with having+past participle

Tags: sentence-meaning, participles, adverbial-phrases

Here are two sentences which look similar:

> 1. Having taken a physics class helped me in calculus.
> 2. Having taken a physics class, It helped me in calculus.

Do they mean same? Or second is wrong? What's the meaning they convey?

Comment: Gerunds vs. Participle Phrases is your concern. Give it a search. Your sentences though need editing.

Comment: @Yuri I can't edit it, i'm not getting any option to edit it.

Comment: The 'edit' link should appear in grey below your question, next to 'share'.

Comment: @snapnail,Done !!!!

Comment: Taken may suggest you have taken a physics class( to students may be). I think attended would be more appropriate here. Having attended physics class helped me in calculus./understand calculus better. As far as second sentence is concerned, it could better be, "I have attended a physics class and it helped me in calculus. That sounds better to me.

Comment: @Vanpram I've changed my question in http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106064/gerundshavingpast-participle-and-beingpast-participle?noredirect=1#comment211570_106064 but this question is still hold, I don't know why.