# Gerunds:Having+past participle and being+past participle

Tags: grammaticality

Here are two sentences:

> My having been to South-Korea helped me learn the languages when I took the classes.
>
> Being accepted to Harvard university was the greatest day of my life.

Is it common or natural way to write such 'having+past participle' and being+past participle construction in formal writing? Or should I use the other alternatives for these? Are these construction encouraged in writing? And What about in spoken English?
Thanks.

source http://www.myenglishteacher.net/gerunds.html

Comment: Proofreading isn't encouraged here. You might want to change your question. That thing that you're looking for is called _gerund_ replacing a noun acting like one and it's different from _present participle phrases_ which replace a clause and acting like one.

Comment: @Yuri yeah! That's exactly what i'm looking for. I don't know how it looks like proof-reading.

Comment: [This](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/participles-and-gerunds) gives you a basic understanding of the difference and [this one](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.html) takes you one step more.

Comment: @Yuri Thanks for links, found helpfull. . .but it's not enough for this question!

Comment: 1. **_Spending time in_ South-Korea helped me learn the languages when I took the classes.** 2. **_The day I was_ accepted to Harvard University was the greatest day of my life.** (It's a proofreading question because there is no specific question on usage or meaning. There are _hundreds_ of ways to rewrite these two sentences.

Comment: @P.E Dent - This is the link http://www.myenglishteacher.net/gerunds.html

Comment: The two examples are you cite in your question are meant to illustrate the _gerund_ in its _perfect_ form ("Having been to...") and in the _passive_ voice ("Being accepted...") They have nothing to do with replacing the gerunds, which is what your question asks about.

Comment: @P.E Dent What i want is to write those sentences in the simple form by removing perfect participle and gerund forms. Because these forms of sentences look complicated for me. That's all

Comment: @P.E Dent I'm also asking 'how to write these sentences by removing. . . .without changing their meanings, so, meaning shouldn't be changed after they are Re writen.

Comment: There are literally _hundreds_ of ways to write these sentences without the gerunds and without changing their meaning. For examples, see my comment above. The gerund is very important and useful in English, and the sentences are not very complicated. If you study and understand the examples in the lesson you linked to, you will be able to eliminate the gerunds yourself!

Comment: For completeness, I see that my previous comment didn't eliminate the gerund in your first example; one of the many ways to this example with that objective in mind is: **_I visited South-Korea, and that helped me learn the languages when I took the classes._**

Comment: @P.E Dent The answer of this question http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106047/past-participle-vs-beingpast-participle/106123#106123 will
also answer this question, two questions one answer

Comment: You ask here: "How to re-write this sentence without changing its meaning by removing the 'being+past participle' from this sentence?" The answer is that there are _hundreds_ of ways to do that. Your other question is specifically about the word _being,_ and there are two answers there, one of which explains how to rewrite the sentences, and one of which runs counter to the doctrine that **"Be (and by extension, "being") doesn't mean anything most of the time"** (which, judging by the upvotes, is a popular belief.)

Comment: yes!!! of course.But what I mean to say is previous question is most important for me compared to this one

Comment: @P.E Dent I've changed my question

Comment: In that link you posted, it has a bit about gerunds in the passive, the same exact construction in your earlier question **There is also a passive form of gerunds.  The passive form of gerunds is formed by using being + past participle.**. So, I was partly right, the voice is passive. Unless the website is wrong, which is always a possibility.

Comment: @Mari-LouA You were right indeed. The _only_ thing you had wrong is that a sentence doesn't have voice - a gerund does, or a clause, but not a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two examples which the OP cited are  formal, the first being *very* formal; and both are in the passive voice.

If I were to recast the two examples into the **active voice**, I would suggest the following:

1. My having been to South-Korea helped me learn the languages when I took the classes.

   - The time **I spent** in South-Korea helped me learn the languages …
2. Being accepted to Harvard university was the greatest day of my life.

   - The time **Harvard University accepted** my application, was the greatest day of my life

Note that *Harvard University* is capitalised, because it is the full and complete name of the institution.

---

- Is the use of gerund + past participle common in formal writing?

It is still used in formal writing but it is, without a shadow of a doubt, becoming less common in speech. If it's used sparingly in an essay, an English teacher might be favourably impressed but if the student resorts to using this type of construction whenever possible, it will sound at best antiquated and, at worst, pompous.

Some people maintain that the passive voice should be used whenever it is required, while others claim an overuse of the passive voice actually presents poor style.

Supporters of Strunk and White's *The Elements of Style* (1918) will say: “Use definite, specific, concrete language”,  *[The active voice is usually more direct and vigorous than the passive:](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html#11)*, and *[The habitual use of the active voice, however, makes for forcible writing. This is true not only in narrative principally concerned with action, but in writing of any kind.](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html#11)*

In the end, choose the construction which you feel most confident with.

P.S Not all the examples of “tame sentences” cited by S&W are actually in the passive voice, and none begin with the gerund + past participle, just thought I'd warn you.