# What's the difference between "Once I've graduated" and "Once I graduate"?

Tags: grammar

Consider theses two sentences:

*Once I have graduated, I will find a job.*

*Once I graduate, I will find a job.*

What's the difference between them?

Of all the resources about the present perfect I've found on the Internet, none talks about using it for a future action, but obviously, I see this use very often in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *present perfect* describes something that happened at an uspecified time and when the exact moment of occurrence isn't important.

Although this usually means "an uspecified time before the present", the *present perfect* is also used in subordinate clauses to talk about an uspecified time in the future (when the main verb is in the present or future tense.)

This usage of the *present perfect* often follows these words and expressions:

- when
- until
- once
- if
- after
- before
- as soon as
- ...and others

> I'll go shopping *when* the rain has stopped.
>   *After* the rain has stopped, I mow the lawn 
>   I'll go shopping *once* the rain has stopped.
>   I'll go shopping *if* the rain has stopped.
>   *Until* the rain has stopped, I won't go shopping.
>   I make nachos *before* the game has started.
>   I'll stop playing *as soon as* this quarter has ended.

Note that we can also (and more frequently do) use the *present simple* to describe the future in these subordinate clauses with no change in meaning.

> I'll go shopping *when* the rain stops.
>   *After* the rain stops, I mow the lawn. 
>   I'll go shopping *once* the rain stops.
>   I'll go shopping *if* the rain stops.
>   *Until* the rain stops, I won't go shopping .
>   I make nachos *before* the game starts.
>   I'll stop playing *as soon as* this quarter ends.

Answer (score 0):

There's really little functional difference between them.  The use of the progressive tense always implies some kind of temporal relationship, but (I think) with instantaneous events it's a "difference that makes no difference".

"Finished" or "completed" can be similar:

> I'll clean my room once I've finished breakfast.
>
> I'll clean my room once I finish breakfast.
>
> Only once Luke has completed his training, will he be ready to face the Emperor.
>
> Only once Luke completes his training, will he be ready to face the Emperor.

As well as other "instantaneous" verbs like "pass/fail".

> Once you've passed History, we can talk about summer camp
>
> One you pass History, we can talk about summer camp.

I'm sure you can think of others.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real difference. Usually, present perfect tense suggests that the event happens only once (or discontinuously), whereas present tense suggests that the event happens regularly (or continuously, depending on the context).

But here, using "once" in the sentence suggests the former. So it makes no difference whether you use present tense or present perfect tense.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In case you haven't do so yet, please take a few minutes to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you will ask some questions of your own! [From review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/47200)

Comment: @P.E Dent I upvoted in your answer.But i don't know why my previous http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106064/gerundshavingpast-participle-and-beingpast-participle question is still on hold, Please vote to reopen it