# "Being helped" vs he/she had been helped

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction

Here are some sentences about "being helped":

1. Share your experiences of being helped by the Air Ambulance.

   Source: http://www.worksopguardian.co.uk/news/share-your-experiences-of-being-helped-by-the-air-ambulance-1-8057024
2. California Nice victim talks about being helped by a stranger
   Nice victim Greg Krentzman from Culver City, Calif, talks about being helped by a good Samaritan after being hit by a truck that killed 80.

   Source:http://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/news/video-1311771/California-Nice-victim-talks-helped-stranger.html
3. Being helped by one of the nurses, the patient slipped and fell.

   (Does it mean "as/while he was being helped"?)

Does "being helped" here refers to "he/she was being helped" or what kind of sentence construction it is ? How "being helped" is different from "had been helped, for example:

> share your experiences you had been helped by the air ambulance.

Comment: Related: [Gerunds:Having+past participle and being+past participle](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106064/gerundshavingpast-participle-and-beingpast-participle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Being helped" is the passive form of "to help", turned into a gerund (a verb that acts like a noun).

> You helped me out of the car
>
> I was helped out of the car (by you).
>
> Being helped out of the car (by you) ...

Gerunds are not complete sentences but require more to explain the full context.  So you can mentally rewrite your example sentences using the passive or active verb, which should help you understand their meaning:

> Share your experiences of being helped by the Air Ambulance.
>
> Share your experiences where you were helped by the Air Ambulance.
>
> Share your experiences where the Air Ambulance helped you.

.

> [He] talks about being helped by a good Samaritan.
>
> [He] talks about when he was helped by a good Samaritan.
>
> [He] talks about when a good Samaritan helped him.

.

> Being helped by one of the nurses, the patient ...
>
> While the patient was helped by one of the nurses ...
>
> While the nurse was helping the patient ...

And so on.

Comment: But I don't know how to use those kind of sentences myself.It would be helpful If I knew the meaning of above sentences with" being+p.p".How can I be able to use those kind of sentences myself ? Is there any rule or what?

Comment: Meaning and usage of .......?

Comment: How can be able to use those kind of sentences using "being+past participle" myself? Or to create such sentences myself?  Is there any rule for it ?    Usage and meaning?

Comment: @yubrajsharma - What you probably want to look up is the [*present continuous* in the *passive voice*](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Green%20Level/G10%20Present%20Cont%20Passive.html).  The present continuous is formed with *to be* and a gerund, for example *I am running.*  Passive voices are formed with *to be* and the past participle, for example *I was chased by a bear.*  If you put them together, you get the present continuous in the passive voice, for example *I am being chased by a bear.*

Comment: @stangdon No, I'm not going to look up about that, I'v already learned  how to create "present continueous in passive voice" and I know how to use it.

Comment: @yubrajsharma - Then I don't think anybody understands what your question is, because that's what's being used here.

Comment: @stangdon I would think Andrew understood my question, but he hasn't even replied my comment. Neither he has edited his question to address my problem, let's see someone is out there to understand my question/problem

Comment: @yubrajsharma I've unpacked this enough that you should be able to figure out the rest. For example, what part of, "While the nurse was helping the patient, the patient slipped and fell" is unclear?  I've already stated that it is *not* an example of the past continuous, and tried to make it clear what it actually is.  If this isn't enough then perhaps you should consider contracting a private English tutor.

Comment: @yubrajsharma, a large part of learning any language is to listen to how native speakers phrase things.  English is so widely spoken that there will be a lot of different styles.  Personally, I rarely use the "being -ing" structure as I think it makes a sentence less understandable.  There is almost always an easier way to say what you want to say.

Comment: @Andrew These days I'm learning English grammar so that It will be easier for me to read and write and even to talk in English. As i'm studying in higher level, I want to learn every kind of sentence construction and their usage/meaning  used in English language.

Comment: @Andrew It seems 'being helped' is the passive participle. For example: "Being helped by the air ambulance" refers to 'you were helped by air ambulance' which is passive of simple past tense 'Air ambulance helped you'

Comment: @Andrew I'm here focusing more on the use of this kind of sentence construction, so that I'll be able to create them. Do I have to start a sentence from 'being+past participle' if the sentence is past tense is in passive? I have heard somewhere that 'being+p.p' is timeless or tense less

Comment: @yubrajsharma I showed how to construct these as the first example in my answer.  "you helped me" -> "I was helped by you" -> "being helped by you".  The way you can use them is either like any other noun ("I enjoy being helped by you") or you can use them as a participle phrase ("Being helped by you, I was able to complete the project").  **However** if you ask *when* you should use these my answer is *don't* -- as I said, personal preference.

Comment: @Andrew Share your experiences of being helped by him=share your experiences where you were helped by him, here, being helped=you were helped

I enjoy being helped by you=I enjoy when I'm helped by you.
Here, "being helped" is working in past and present tense. Isn't it ?

Comment: Andrew "Being+past participle" fits in both present and past passive finite clauses?